# Firebase FCM iOS notification

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-ios

I am using two different firebase database on my flutter application. Let say primary and secondary database.

When I am sending message from cloud messaging by using FCM tokens, from primary firebase database it's working but it's not working from secondary firebase database.

This is happening only with iOS devices, but it's working perfectly on android devices.

[image]

Please help me here.

Comment: are you having multiple database on same firebase project? I do not get it. If you're using multiple firebase projects in single app, you have to initialise firebase by calling **Firebase. initializeApp** for both projects

Comment: Two firebase projects on single flutter application.

Comment: different project should have different `vapidkey` and `GoogleService-Info.plist`(iOS) and `google-service,json`(android). im not sure its possible work even in android. because you need to repalce that file in your code

Comment: Thanks for the response, its working fine with andriod